# Отправка токенов в блокчейне Harmony

Tags: node.js, web3.js

Пытаюсь со своего метамаска кинуть на другой метамаск немного своих токенов, которые находятся в блокчейне Harmony, однако всегда получаю еррор, мол денег на покрытие газа мало. **(Returned error: insufficient funds for transfer)**
На метамаске, с которого отправляю есть 271 one (Harmony) и больше 5 миллионов только что созданных мной токенов, которые я хочу кинуть на другой аккаунт метамаск

Код:

```
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3('https://api.s0.b.hmny.io');

const contractAddress = 'contract address'; 
const contractABI = [{
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [
      {
          "name": "_to",
          "type": "address"
      },
      {
          "name": "_value",
          "type": "uint256"
      }
  ],
  "name": "transfer",
  "outputs": [
      {
          "name": "",
          "type": "bool"
      }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}]; 

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

async function sendTransaction() {
  try {
    const privateKeyHex = 'my private key metamask'; 
    const privateKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(privateKeyHex, 'hex');
    const senderAccount = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKeyBuffer);
    const senderAddress = senderAccount.address;
    console.log(senderAddress)
    const receiverAddress = 'recivier key metamask'; 

    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress);
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    console.log(gasPrice)

    const amount = '1'; 
    const amountWei = web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether'); 

    const rawTransaction = {
      'from': senderAddress,
      'nonce': nonce,
      'gasPrice': gasPrice,
      'to': contractAddress,
      'value': '0x0',
      'data': contract.methods.transfer(receiverAddress, amountWei).encodeABI(),
    };

    const signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, privateKeyHex);
    const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
    
    console.log('Transaction sent, hash:', transactionReceipt.transactionHash);
    console.log('Receipt:', transactionReceipt);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending transaction:', error);
  }
}

sendTransaction();
```